# AWS Lambda: does it matter if handlers are sync vs async, w.r.t. concurrent calls?

Tags: aws-lambda, python-asyncio

For AWS Lambda handlers, does it matter if the code is async vs sync (eg `async def` vs `def`), with respect to the concurrency performance of multiple calls to that Lambda function? That is, if I write a synchronous function, will that function be called "asynchronously" *anyway* due to the way AWS internally handles Lambda invocations from separate calls? Or will the function start processing UserA, and queue UserB's request until it has completed UserA?

Backstory: I'm writing some Python + SQLAlchemy Lambda functions. SQLAlchemy 1.4 just released asyncio support, but there will be some re-write overhead on my part. I'm wondering if I can just write traditional synchronous Python code without concurrency consideration on Lambda (where concurrency is something I'd definitely need to consider for custom Flask / FastAPI code).

Comment: Does Lambda support handlers defined with `async def`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more than one request to invoke a lambda at the same time the service will attempt to run multiple instances of the lambda. You may run into throttling due to the concurrency limits on either the lambda itself, or the account. Lambda does not queue requests to the same lambda function. A function is never processing more than one request at a time. Even in cases where the system is providing a queuing mechanism to handle the requests, they are not a thread queue, like you might have with a server. They are really just internal SQS queues that are invoking the lambda with one request at a time.

Comment: Got it. So even if I made the function async, that doesn't mean _that_ Lambda instance will handle concurrent calls. Each call is its own Lambda invocation?

Comment: That's correct. Async doesn't really do a lot for you in the case of a lambda function. If you happen to be doing something that is multi-threaded, and you're making I/O requests, then there could be some benefit, but I'd say that's a rare scenario.

Comment: Am I right to assume, that the same answer can be given for JVM lambdas?

Comment: What about use cases that use reactive streams on a thread pool (on JVM). Could async IO be of some help in this case on AWS lambda?

Comment: Async calls for IO can be advantageous if you are making more than one at a time within the same request. For example, if you need to call a couple of HTTP endpoints based on the request you can make those asynchronously and wait for both to return before proceeding, rather than calling each synchronously and wait for the network one at a time. As for how Java handles that I don’t really know, but it would be the same as any other Java code. Just be aware that you are most likely on a single core.